# Looking for specific episode of Cyborg 009 (1979) where Heinrich makes a difficult decision

Tags: anime, episode-identification, cyborg

In the late 70's and early 80s in New York City, Japanese programming would take over on Saturday evenings on UHF Channel 47 which normally ran Spanish programming. Shows like Yuusha Raideen, Ikkyu-san, Himitsu Sentai Gorenger, Captain Harlock, and Galaxy Express 999 were run in Japanese with English subtitles.

I'm looking for a specific episode of the Japanese anime [Cyborg 009](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyborg_009) from the 1979 series. The episode involves Heinrich (Cyborg 004 - has a hand with machine gun fingertips, rocket/mortar launcher in leg).

I distinctly remember (or perhaps misremember) a scene where the heroes are trapped on a side of a mountain? and the enemy has turned a small child (girl?) into a walking cyborg bomb headed toward them. Not sure if there were civilians with the group but I do remember a few scenes of the group inter-cut with the child walking up toward them at dusk/night. Heinrich (Cyborg 004) has to make a difficult decision of shooting and blowing up the child in order to save the team with him saying *"Call me killer"*.

Now that I'm recalling it, all I can remember are blues and purples in the scene, even the words seem a bit too extreme so I may be conflating other TV shows/movies of the era into that memory, or a result of the 'interesting' translation choices used at the time.

I have rewatched some the early episodes that I've been able to find on the internet but nothing there clicks, and haven't been able to find the later ones. I'm looking for episode title/number and interested to know how close my memory is to the episode story.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's episode 43, **"[The Secret of the 3 Brothers](https://myanimelist.net/anime/4690/Cyborg_009_1979/episode/43)"**. Pretty much exactly as you describe it. I had the same memory for 30 years and just found it. Funny how life works.

Towards the end of the episode, from around the 18 minute mark.

Comment: Thanks as it seems old series like "Cyborg 009 (1979)" are not completely lost to time. Curious as to what the 1980's USA broadcast translation was but Heinrich call himself a 'shinigami' at the fateful moment.